# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework code-first: no errors but tables aren't populated correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, relational-database

I'm currently making a ticketing system using MVC4 Entity Framework. I've populated my tables in my SQL server but there's only a few columns that aren't correct. Firstly I want to apologise for the amount of code but they are all needed for referencing!

I only want people to check if I'm mapping my model properly because in image(1) some values are missing.

It is very important that you look at the two images provided below for a clearer picture as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

The image(1) [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKWYj.png) shows what I want my tables to be like and shows all the Primary and Foreign keys for each of my classes.

This image(2)[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRZDL.jpg) shows my entity diagram
So my ideal situation is :
User can create multiple tickets and they can only assign them to one admin(Which fixes the issue the is on the ticket).

Each Tickets will be identified by the TicketID so on the Admin table it should have the AdminID,UserID(The person who submitted the ticket), TicketID and AdminRole.

Each AdminID can be assigned to one user but not all user must be assigned to one AdminID

DepotID,DepartmentID and Category are pretty straight forward.
DepotID and DepartmentID must be assigned to a user and each user can only have 1 DepotID and DepartmentID

CategoryID must be assigned to each ticket so each ticket can only have one CategoryID

User.cs

```
public class User
{

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
    }
   // public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
   // [ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]
   // public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AdminID")]
    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }


    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
    public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }

    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

}
```

Ticket.cs

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("TicketID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

Depot.cs

```
public class Depot
{
    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Department.cs

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Administrator.cs

```
public class Administrator
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }        
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AdminRole { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration.cs(Seed method)

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext context)
    {
        var departments = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department { DepartmentID = 1, Name = "IT"},
            new Department { DepartmentID = 2, Name = "Admin" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 3, Name = "Human Resources"},
            new Department { DepartmentID = 4, Name = "Mechanics" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 5, Name = "Directors" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 6, Name = "Operations"}

        };
        departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();


        var depots = new List<Depot>
        {
            new Depot { DepotID = 1, Name = "Porana"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 2, Name = "Far North"},


        };
        depots.ForEach(s => context.Depots.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var users = new List<User>
    {
        new User { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1 ,DepotID = 1},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1},

    };


        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.FirstMidName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();


        var administrator = new List<Administrator>
        {
            new Administrator {AdminID = 1, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL1", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 1),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
            new Administrator {AdminID = 2, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL2", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 2),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
            new Administrator {AdminID = 3, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL3", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 3),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() }

        };
        administrator.ForEach(s => context.Administrators.AddOrUpdate(p => p.AdminID, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var categories = new List<Category>
        {
            new Category {CategoryID = 0001, Title = "Desktop"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0002, Title = "Mobile"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0003, Title = "Menzits"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0004, Title = "XMPRO"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0005, Title = "Con-X"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0006, Title = "Promapp"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0007, Title = "QGIS"},
        };
        categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Title, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var tickets = new List<Ticket>
        {
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Con-X" ).CategoryID,
                Issue = ("Test Error NEW TEST"),
                AdminID = 1,
                Priority = Priority.High
            },
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Desktop" ).CategoryID,
                Issue = ("Test Error 2"),
                AdminID = 2,
                Priority = Priority.Med
            },
        };


        foreach (Ticket e in tickets)
        {
            var ticketInDataBase = context.Tickets.Where(
                s =>
                    s.User.UserID == e.UserID &&
                    s.Category.CategoryID == e.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
            if (ticketInDataBase == null)
            {
                context.Tickets.Add(e);
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

IssueContext.cs

```
   public class IssueContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Administrators).WithMany(i => i.Tickets)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("TicketID")
                    .MapRightKey("AdministratorID")
                    .ToTable("AdministratorsTickets"));


            modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
                       .HasKey(e => e.UserID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Administrator) // Mark StudentAddress is optional for Student
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.User); // Create inverse relationship


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Note:

Your `Administrator` entity mapping is incorrect. You are marking UserId as a **PrimaryKey**, so when an entity is inserted to Administrator table, it's automatically sets UserId as a new identity, so in your picture you see UserId increasing incrementally. Instead you should mark your AdminID as primary key:

```
[Key]
public int AdminID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("User")]
public int UserID { get; set; }
```

You should also mark UserID for your User entity as a primary key:

```
[Key]
public int UserID { get; set; }
```

Second Note:

Your Administrator and User are mapped to tickets using **one to many** relationship, which means that **1 administrator has X tickets, and 1 user has Y tickets**. That means, that Ticket table contains foreign keys to Administrator entity and to User entity: AdminID and UserID in your picture. You can see it on your picture. If you leave TicketId in both classes, that would mean that you have a **one to one** relationship along with **one to many** which is really weird and not gonna work.  So you need to remove TicketId fully from your User and Administrator tables

Third Note:

You would also need to add direct references to User and to Administrator from your Ticket entity, add `[ForeignKey]` attribute to each and specify the property you are using as a foreign key for them. You also need to remove Administrators collection, since if you leave it that way your relationship will be **many to many**:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }

    public string Issue { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AdminID")]
    public Administrator Admin { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }    
}
```

Fourth Note:

Also you have Required-Optional one to one relationship between User and Administrator, which maps in the following way:

Your Administrator entity has `int UserId`, but your User entity does not have AdministratorId, Entity Framework will correctly map this relationship from the side of Administrator. If you keep circular reference like you have now - Administrator has UserId and User has AdministratorId - it will cause a lot of issues, since it's unsupported by EF in a correct way, as far as I remember.

You should carefully read Entity Framework documentation about generating database schema, otherwise you will not be able to transform your SQL schema to correct EF entities:

Data annotations in Entity Framework:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583

Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

Comment: You don't need the Key and ForeignKey annotations when you follow convention (class name + "Id"). The one for AdminId would be needed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @SteveGreene, you are totally right. But I believe, it's overall a good practice to provide explicit annotations from my experience, unless you are using your custom annotation or everyone in a team are quite good with EF. In this specific case, given the OP is learning EF, I believe it's overall a good practice to go full-explicit.

Comment: @raderick Thank you for posting a detailed answer.We use `public User User { get; set; }` instead of `public virtual User User { get; set; }` because they are Required-optional 1 to 1 relationship? How would I be able to get a table which shows all the tickets the admin is assigned so he can fix it along with the User to know who created the ticket? When you say "Entity Framework will correctly map this relationship from the side of Administrator." Does that mean I'll never be able to make them show correctly on both tables because in the User table AdminID column is 0s.

Comment: @user6006661 `public virtual User User { get; set; }` makes your User property access use Lazy Load. If you remove it, you have to explicitely load it using `.Include(x=>x.User)` when loading Ticket or Administrator.
To get all Tickets for Administrator you just load Administrator entity and get data from Tickets property, which will have the association to I am not quite sure about your last question. Did you read the links provided?

Comment: Yes I'm reading it. I'm just trying to find a way to make Admin,User and Ticket work. Admin:Ticket 1:Many then User:Ticket 1:1 then merging them into the desired table i posted in the question. I want the Admin table to display both TicketID and UserID so they the admin knows which ticket he needs to attend to AND be able to check which users created it. I also want the User to know what his TicketID is AND which Admin via adminID is working on his problem.  "The many-to-many relationship involves defining a third table (called a junction or join table)"  Is my junction table my Ticket Table?

Comment: @user6006661 I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, so all I could do is fix your mapping errors. You should probably try working with your application further and see if your schema does not fit your needs.

Comment: @raderick Sorry to bother you again! After reading the links I tweaked the mappings again and I just have one more problem with one of my Admin Tables not showing TicketID correctly Link here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815113/mvc-entity-framework-mapping-correct-but-tables-incorrect

Comment: @user6006661 if you want TicketId filled in for Administrator table, then you need a 1 to 1 relationship between Administrator and Ticket. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: @raderick So that the Admin that's reading the table will know what ticket he's suppose to fix from reading the TicketID and which user submitted it from the UserID. This is the confusing part for me whether TIcket and Admin is a 1 to 1 relationship or 1 to many. One admin can have many tickets assigned to him but one ticket can only be assigned to one admin.

Comment: @user6006661 you are expressing your current database schema. To achieve this you should remove TicketId from Administrator and this will work fine. If you need Admin-Ticket association you should look at your tickets table, it already contains TicketId and AdministratorId. That fits your requirement - each ticket can be assigned only to 1 admin, and on the other hand admin can have many tickets.

Comment: @raderick I think this was my confusion. I kept wanting the Admin to see which ticket he has through the Admin Table when he could just look at the Ticket Table. Thanks for everything I finally got this figured out! Sorry I don't have enough rep to upvote all your comments! I'll be sure to do it when I have enough rep.

Comment: @user6006661 glad I finally helped you!