# MVC Entity Framework Mapping Correct but Tables incorrect

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, relational-database

I'm currently making a ticketing system using MVC4 Entity Framework.

Relations between 3 classes
User to Admin = 1:0...1   1 to 0 or 1 = Few users will have admin status but not all.

Admin to Ticket = 1:*|1 to Many  = Admins can be assigned with more than 1 ticket but one ticket can only be assigned to one admin

User to Ticket = 1:*|1 to Many = Users can open multiple tickets but one ticket can only have one user.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDt2E.png) are what my current tables look like.

My issue is why is my admin table displaying incorrectly see [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK3LZ.png)

I want each ticket to be identified by a TicketID so on the Admin table it should have the AdminID(Admin that's going to fix the issue),UserID(The person who submitted the ticket) and TicketID.

I followed a tutorial that shows 1 to many relationships where Team = Admin(1) to Players = Tickets(Many)

Player.cs ( Tickets)

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; } // This is new
}
```

Team.cs (Admin)

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime Founded { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<player> Players { get; set; } // This is new
}
```

My code.

User.cs

```
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
        }
   //     public int AdminiID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AdminID")]
        public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

        public string AdminRole { get; set; }


        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }


        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }

        //public int TicketID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

    }
```

Ticket.cs

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("AdminID")]
    //public Administrator Admin { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Administor.cs

```
public class Administrator
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }        
    [StringLength(50)]

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration.cs

```
namespace RecreationServicesTicketingSystem.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext context)
        {
            var departments = new List<Department>
            {
                new Department { DepartmentID = 1, Name = "IT"},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 2, Name = "Admin" },
                new Department { DepartmentID = 3, Name = "Human Resources"},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 4, Name = "Mechanics" },
                new Department { DepartmentID = 5, Name = "Directors" },
                new Department { DepartmentID = 6, Name = "Operations"}

            };
            departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
            context.SaveChanges();


            var depots = new List<Depot>
            {
                new Depot { DepotID = 1, Name = "Porana"},
                new Depot { DepotID = 2, Name = "Far North"},


            };
            depots.ForEach(s => context.Depots.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var users = new List<User>
        {
            new User { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1,AdminRole="Administrator LVL1"},
            new User { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1,AdminRole="Administrator LVL2"},
            new User { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1 ,DepotID = 1,AdminRole="Administrator LVL3"},
            new User { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1},

        };


            users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.FirstMidName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();


            var administrator = new List<Administrator>
            {
                new Administrator {AdminID = 1,  User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 1),
                /*Tickets = new List<Ticket>()*/ },
                new Administrator {AdminID = 2, User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 2),
                /*Tickets = new List<Ticket>()*/ },
                new Administrator {AdminID = 3,  User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 3),
                /*Tickets = new List<Ticket>() */}

            };
            administrator.ForEach(s => context.Administrators.AddOrUpdate(p => p.AdminID, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category {CategoryID = 0001, Title = "Desktop"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0002, Title = "Mobile"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0003, Title = "Menzits"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0004, Title = "XMPRO"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0005, Title = "Con-X"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0006, Title = "Promapp"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0007, Title = "QGIS"},
            };
            categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Title, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var tickets = new List<Ticket>
            {
                new Ticket {
                    UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                    CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Con-X" ).CategoryID,
                    Issue = ("Con-X Login Error"),
                    AdminID = 1,
                    Priority = Priority.High
                },
                new Ticket {
                    UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                    CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Desktop" ).CategoryID,
                    Issue = ("Can't remote access C0123"),
                    AdminID = 2,
                    Priority = Priority.Med
                },
            };


            foreach (Ticket e in tickets)
            {
                var ticketInDataBase = context.Tickets.Where(
                    s =>
                        s.User.UserID == e.UserID &&
                        s.Category.CategoryID == e.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
                if (ticketInDataBase == null)
                {
                    context.Tickets.Add(e);
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything look OK.  If you have many to one for admins to tickets there are some (many) tickets that belong to one admin so they should have an AdminID column. And no column on the admin table for this relationship. That's how it works!